# Simulate Multi-Threading in MS Access (VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wrote a VBA script that runs in an Access database. The script looks up values on various tables and assigns an attribute to a main table based on the combination of values.

The script works as intended, however, I am working with millions of records so it takes an unacceptably long time.

I would like to break the process up into smaller parts and run the script concurrently on separate threads.

Before I start attempting to build a solution, I would like to know:

1. Based on your experience, would this increase performance? Or would the process take just as long?
2. I am looking at using Powershell or VBScript to accomplish this. Any obstacles to look out for?

Please Note: Due to the client this will run on, I have to use Access for the backend and if I use Powershell it will have to be version 1.0.

I know these are very vague questions but any feedback based on prior experience is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: First figure out if the task is CPU bound or IO bound. If they are CPU bound, multi-threading will likely help (but only if the machine has multiple cores, obviously). If they are IO bound, running on more cores will not make much difference - other than added overhead for thread management.

Comment: My experience with this problem is that you can speed things up quite a bit by fixing up the SQL and table structure. Also writing new records by using csv import rather than SQL insert will boost speed quite drastically.

Comment: Perhaps you should be writing out the updates to CSV or a table as per Pynner's suggestion and then running all updates as a single query.

Comment: @driis - Thank you for this suggestion. I had not considered CPU bound v. I/O bound. I did some research regarding the two and I learned a lot. It gave me some ideas on solutions I had not thought of before.

Comment: @Pynner and Remou - Thank you both for your suggestion regarding CSV. I am going to try this as a solution. I would like to avoid the simulation of multi-threading if at all possible due to the complexity that it could introduce. I will post back once I have built and tested to let you know the results. Thanks again

Comment: I suggest you use something that supports multi-threading to write your front-end, like .Net. The other comments here about CPU vs IO should also be taken seriously, but almost any very modern computer will be quickly limited without multi-threading in the type of processing/scenario you are working with. If you still with single threading you'll need to find the most powerful single-core processor possible, but even that is really kind of a bad work-around. You might also find that MS Access will become your limiting factor. SQL Server Express is free, after all.

Comment: Thanks HK1. I agree that a .Net or pure VB front-end would make more sense. I would also prefer to use SQL Server for the back-end. However this is being done in a corporate environment where it would likely be an act of congress just to get SQL Server or Visual Studio installed. I am also worried about Access' ability to handle this much data and the 2GB limit. I may have to end up lobbying for SQL Server, but I want to exhaust all other options before I go that route. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post back with my final solution on this...

I tried the following ways to assign an attribute to a main table based on a combination of values from other tables for a 60,000 record sample size:

```
Solution 1: Used a combination of SQL queries and FSO Dictionary objects to assign attribute
Result: 60+ minutes to update 60,000 records

Solution 2: Ran script from Solution 1 concurrently from 3 separate instances of Excel
Result: CPU was maxed out (Instance 1 - 50% of CPU, Instances 2 and 3 - 25% each); stopped the code after an hour since it wasn't a viable solution

Solution 3: Tried using SQL UPDATE queries to update main table with the attribute
Result: This failed because apparently Access does not allow for a join on an UPDATE sub-query (or I just stink at writing SQL)

Solution 4 (Best Result): Selected all records from main table that matched the criteria for each attribute, 
 output the records into csv and assigned the attribute to all records in the csv file. 
 This created a separate file for each attribute, all in the same format. I then 
 imported and appended all of the records from the csv files into a new main table.  
Result: 2.5 minutes to update 60,000 records
```

Special thanks to Pynner and Remou who suggested writing the data out to csv.

I never would have thought that this would be the quickest way to update the records with the attribute. I probably would have scrapped the project thinking it was impossible to accomplish with Access and VBA had you not made this suggestion. Thank you so much for sharing your wisdom!